# Checking if the value is there in any specified column of the same table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I wanted to check if the value of a particular row of a column is present in the other column.

df:

```
   sno  id1 id2 id3 
    1   1,2 7   1,2,7,22
    2   2   8,9 2,8,9,15,17
    3   1,5 6   1,5,6,17,33
    4   4       4,12,18
    5       9   9,14
```

output:

for a particular given row,

```
for i  in sno:   
    if id1 in id3 : 
      score = 50
    elif id2 in id3:
      score = 50 

    if id1 in id3 and id2 in id3:
       score = 75
```

I finally want my score out of that logic.

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: if  id1 is in id3 colum, i want a variable score as points 50, if id2 is in id3, score is 50, if both id1 nad id2 re prsent i want score as 75

Comment: there is double 50 ? it is still same value ?

Comment: Yes, if anyone of the column is there, then score is 50. if both the columns are present, then the score is 75

Comment: For first row need present `1 OR 2` in df3 or `1 AND 2` in df3 ?

Comment: 1 and 2 in df3, both should satisfy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert all values to sets with split and then compare by `issubset`, also `and bool(a)` is used for omit empty sets (created from missing values):

```
print (df)
   sno  id1  id2          id3
0    1  1,2    7   1,20,70,22
1    2    2  8,9  2,8,9,15,17
2    3  1,5    6  1,5,6,17,33
3    4    4  NaN      4,12,18
4    5  NaN    9         9,14

def convert(x):
    return set(x.split(',')) if isinstance(x, str) else set([])

cols = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']
df1 = df[cols].applymap(convert)

m1 = np.array([a.issubset(b) and bool(a) for a, b in zip(df1['id1'], df1['id3'])])
m2 = np.array([a.issubset(b) and bool(a) for a, b in zip(df1['id2'], df1['id3'])])

df['new'] = np.select([m1 & m2, m1 | m2], [75, 50], np.nan)
print (df)
   sno  id1  id2          id3   new
0    1  1,2    7   1,20,70,22   NaN
1    2    2  8,9  2,8,9,15,17  75.0
2    3  1,5    6  1,5,6,17,33  75.0
3    4    4  NaN      4,12,18  50.0
4    5  NaN    9         9,14  50.0
```

Comment: when I use the  convert function, if the column value is only a single digit, its returning null set.

Comment: for ex : in sno 2, the value of id1 is 2, when you run this through convert function the value is empty {}.

Comment: @pylearner - yes, need convert columns to strings first like `df1 = df[cols].astype(str).applymap(convert)`

Comment: if suppose, id1 has 2,3 and id3 has 3,4,5... if any element in id1 is there, i want to consider it. seems like issubset() doesnt provide me that.

Comment: sorry, I should have let you know this before, but just saw the variables changing in my dataset.